# GET data from Couchdb using Guzzle in php

Tags: php, couchdb, guzzle, couchdb-2.0

I'm getting data from Couchdb to PHP using Guzzle library. Now I fetch data in POST format like this:

[image]

But I need response like this:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "message": "Success",
    "device_info": {
                "_id": "00ab897bcb0c26a706afc959d35f6262",
                "_rev": "2-4bc737bdd29bb2ee386b967fc7f5aec9",
                "parent_id": "PV-409",
                "child_device_id": "2525252525",
                "app_name": "Power Clean - Antivirus & Phone Cleaner App",
                "package_name": "com.lionmobi.powerclean",
                "app_icon": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/uaC_9MLfMwUy6pOyqntqywd4HyniSSxmTfsiJkF2jQs9ihMyNLvsCuiOqrNxNYFq5ko=s3840",
                "last_app_used_time": "12:40:04",
                "last_app_used_date": "2019-03-12"

        "bookmark": "g1AAAABweJzLYWBgYMpgSmHgKy5JLCrJTq2MT8lPzkzJBYorGBgkJllYmiclJxkkG5klmhuYJaYlW5paphibppkZmRmB9HHA9BGlIwsAq0kecQ",
        "warning": "no matching index found, create an index to optimize query time"
    } }
```

I only remove "docs": `[{}]` -> Anyone know I remove this ?

check My code:

```
$response = $client->post(
                        "/child_activity_stat/_find",
                        [GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON => ['selector' => ['parent_id' => ['$eq' => $userid], 'child_device_id' => ['$eq' => $deviceid]],]]
                    );

                    if ($response->getStatusCode() == 200) {

                        $result = json_decode($response->getBody());
                        $r   = $response->getBody();



                        json_output(200, array(

                            'status'      => 200,
                            'message'     => 'Success',
                            "device_info" =>   $result
                        ));

                    }
```

Comment: Why do you _need_ it like this? All the info is already there. Also, your needed response is faulty

Comment: Becuase i need data in this formate but couchdb return data in "docs": [{}]

Comment: if any info already there please provide me link ? i check it thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to modify your data structure.

**NOTE**: Maybe you should add a limit of 1 if you want to only get one document. You will also need to validate that the result['docs'] is not empty.

Example:

```
<?php
$response = $client->post(
    "/child_activity_stat/_find",
    [GuzzleHttp\ RequestOptions::JSON => ['selector' => ['parent_id' => ['$eq' => $userid], 'child_device_id' => ['$eq' => $deviceid]], ]]
);

if ($response->getStatusCode() == 200) {

    // Parse as array
    $result = json_decode($response->getBody(),true);

    // Get the first document.
    $firstDoc = $result['docs'][0];

    // Remove docs from the response
    unset($result['docs']);

    //Merge sanitized $result with $deviceInfo
    $deviceInfo = array_merge_recursive($firstDoc,$result);   


    json_output(200, array(
        'status' => 200,
        'message' => 'Success',
        "device_info" => $deviceInfo
    ));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In couchdb use **PUT** request is used to edit or to add data and **DELETE** remove data

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
// Put request for edit
$client->put('http://your_url', [
  'body'            => [
     'parent_id' => ['$eq' => $userid], 
     'child_device_id' => ['$eq' => $deviceid]
  ],
  'allow_redirects' => false,
  'timeout'         => 5
]);
// To delete
$client->delete('htt://my-url', [
   'body' = [
      data
   ]
]);
```

Comment: But i'm get data using Guzzle not using Curl

Comment: @muhammadabubakar now you can see it with guzzle

Comment: thanks for reply. i get data in "docs": [{}] but i don't need in this format please check question again

Comment: @muhammadabubakar i think it's configuration error not the code. Please verify all your config.